# cURL and node give the same error, but can't fix node the same way

Tags: node.js, http, curl, https

My code seems pretty solid but it returns no body and status code 500. Interestingly, when I try to do it with cURl the same thing would happen, until I changed the http to https, then it worked perfectly. I feel like the same thing is happening in node, except its already https?

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  host: "*******", // IP Address
  port: *****,
  path: '/***/***/***',
  method: 'POST',
  auth: '***:***'
};

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
```

The Error is:

```
STATUS: 500
HEADERS: {"content-length":"61","content-type":"application/json","server":"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0","date":"Thu, 08 Sep 2016 10:23:48 GMT","connection":"close"}
BODY: "The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty."
```

Comment: The server expects body content, and you're not passing any?

Comment: So if the cURL command is:
curl -k -v -u *****:****https://ipAddress:PortNumber/Path/query

I'm guessing the query is the body, but how do i send that in the options?

Comment: Is that the cURL command you're using? I would have expected `-X POST` to make it a POST request, like you're doing in your Node code (unless you're also passing a `-d`?).

Comment: That is definitely it :/

Comment: So try and see if it works better if you replace `POST` with `GET` in your Node code.

Comment: Its better, but I know get error 400 and the body says I have an incomplete uri. Thanks for you help@

Comment: Can you add the exact (redacted) cURL command line to your question? Also, take a look [at this module](https://github.com/nickcarneiro/curlconverter).

Comment: Its all good! I altered the path and it works now with the method GET. Thank you@